# tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU with sigmoid layer

Tags: validation, binary, tf.keras, sigmoid, keras-metrics

I have a network for semantic segmentation and the last layer of my model applies a sigmoid activation, so all predictions are scaled between 0-1. There is this validation metric tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes), which compares classified predictions (0 or 1) with validation (0 or 1). So if i make a prediction and apply this metric, will it automatically map the continuous predictions to binary with threshold = 0.5? Are there any possibilities to manually define the threshold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU` will not automatically map the continuous predictions to binary with threshold = 0.5.

It will convert the continuous predictions to its binary, by taking the binary digit before decimal point as predictions like `0.99` as `0`, `0.50` as `0`, `0.01` as `0`, `1.99` as `1`, `1.01` as `1` etc when `num_classes=2`. **So basically if your predicted values are between `0` to `1` and `num_classes=2`, then everything is considered `0` unless the prediction is `1`.**

Below are the experiments to justify the behavior in `tensorflow version 2.2.0`:

**All binary result :**

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2)
_ = m.update_state([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1])
m.result().numpy()
```

**Output -**

```
1.0
```

**Change one prediction to continuous 0.99 -** Here it considers `0.99` as `0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2)
_ = m.update_state([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0.99])
m.result().numpy()
```

Output -

```
0.5833334
```

**Change one prediction to continuous 0.01 -** Here it considers `0.01` as `0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2)
_ = m.update_state([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0.01, 1, 1])
m.result().numpy()
```

**Output -**

```
1.0
```

**Change one prediction to continuous 1.99 -** Here it considers `1.99` as `1`.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2)
_ = m.update_state([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1.99])
m.result().numpy()
```

**Output -**

```
1.0
```

**So ideal way is to define a function to convert the continuous to binary before evaluating the `MeanIoU`.**

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @WillemBoone - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(remember to replace the space with tab):

```
def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
    th = 0.5
    y_pred_ = tf.to_int32(y_pred > th)
    score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_iou(y_true, y_pred_, 2)
    K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
        score = tf.identity(score)
    return score
```